# count rows multiple columns

Tags: sql, teradata-sql-assistant

I want to count rows based on multiple columns and with a specific value in a column. Please check the attached table.

Count the value of:

```
ID Date Action = 'C'
```

I tried

`COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Date, Action = 'C') AS Count`, but it didn't work. Does one of you know how to calculate this field?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Why doesn't row 3 have a count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
SELECT . . .,
       (CASE WHEN Action = 'C'
             THEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Date, Action)
        END) as c_count
```

This puts the count in rows with `Action = 'C'`.  If you want the count in all rows, then:

```
SELECT . . .,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Action = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Date) as c_count
```

Answer (score 0):

is it what you want to do ?

```
select 
     ID, 
     Date, 
     Action, 
     case Action 
         when 'C' then COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Date)
         else null
     end as count
from your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want :

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*)
        from table t1
        where t1.date = t.date and t1.id = t.id and t1.action = 'C'
       )
from table t;
```